# remove value from the list

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have a list of checkboxes. Upon clicking on each of the checkboxes i am  adding the value to the hidden variable. But the question is if I want to remove the value from the list upon unchecking the checkbox . How this piece cab be done

here is the hidden form variable

```
<input name="IDList[]" type="hidden" id="IDList" value="" />
```

and the jquery

```
$(".myCheckboxClass").change(function() {
    var output = 0;
    $(".myCheckboxClass").change(function() {
        if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
            output += ", " + $(this).val();
        } else {
            output = $.grep(output, function(value) {
                return value != $(this).val();
            });
        }
        $("#IDList").val(output);
    });
});
```

Comment: How are you storing thev values? In an object?

Comment: Could you add the code that you are using?

Comment: here is the hidden form variable<input name="bodyIDList[]" type="hidden" id="bodyIDList" value="" />

Comment: here is the hidden form variable<input name="IDList[]" type="hidden" id="IDList" value="" /> and the jquery $(".myCheckboxClass").change(function() {
           
   var output = 0;               $(".myCheckboxClass").change(function() {                         if( $(this).is(":checked") ) {             output += ", " + $(this).val();                       }else {                          output = $.grep(output, function(value) {              return value !=  $(this).val();             });            }                              $("#IDList").val(output );                            })

Comment: @erik, I updated your question with the code you posted in the comment. check it to see if it is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this: (demo)  http://jsfiddle.net/wesbos/5N2kb/1/

we use an object called `vals` to store the info. ADding and removing as we check/uncheck.

```
var vals = {};

$('input[type=checkbox]').click(function() {
    var that = $(this);
    if (that.is(':checked')) {
        console.log(this.name);
       vals[this.name] = "In your Object";
    }
    else {
        delete vals[this.name]; 
    }
    console.log(vals);

});
```

Comment: Yes it does, check the example

Comment: if I foolow the link the code does nothing . nothing get outputed

Comment: How do you put this result into the hidden variable

Comment: $('#IDList').attr('value',vals);

Comment: the values are in the object. Maybe you should do a little reading on the basics on JS

Answer (score 0):

Following your logic, you could do this:

```
$('#IDList').data('value', []);

$(".myCheckboxClass").change(function() {
    var list = $('#IDList').data('value');

    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
        list.push($(this).val());
    } else {
        var indexToRemove = list.indexOf($(this).val());
        list.splice(indexToRemove, 1);
    }
    $('#IDList').val(list);
});
```

But if you only care about the value of `#IDList` upon data submission or other actions, you probably want to consider an alternative approach: collating the checked values when you need them.

```
$('#form').submit(function() {
    var list = $('input.myCheckboxClass:checked', this).map(function() {
        return $(this).val();
    }).get();

    $('#IDList').val(list);
});
```

See both of the above in action: http://jsfiddle.net/william/F6gVg/1/.